# MarkLogic "XDMP-FRAGTOOLARGE" error while storing 200MB+ File using REST

Tags: rest, marklogic

When i try to store a 200MB+ xml file to marklogic using **REST** it gives the following error "`XDMP-FRAGTOOLARGE: Fragment of /testdata/upload/submit.xml too large for in-memory storage`".

I have tried the Fragment Roots and Fragment Parents option but still gets the same error.

But when i store the file without '**.xml**' extension in uri. it saves the file but not **Xquery** operations can be performed on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MarkLogic won't be able to derive the mime from the uri without extension. It will then fall back to storing it as binary.

I think that if you would use xdmp:document-load from QConsole, you might be able to load it correctly, as that will not try to hold the entire document in memory first. It won't help you much though, you will likely hit the same error elsewhere. The REST api will have to pass it through in memory, so that won't work like this.

You could raise memory settings in the Admin UI, but you are generally better off by splitting your input. MarkLogic Content Pump (MLCP) will allow you to do so using the aggregate_record options. That will split the file into smaller pieces based on a particular element, and store these as separate documents inside MarkLogic.

HTH!

Comment: One big picture footnote on Geert's good advice: when modelling in MarkLogic, it's best if each document is an instance of an entity (containing any subentities that never stand alone and denormalizing searchable labels with references to other entities). If you're familiar with relational databases, think of a document as a row, not a table.

Comment: Ehennum's advice is a great one. But I would not say (comparing to relational modelling) "*a row*", but rather "*an entity, typically represented by several related rows from several tables*." A good example is an invoice. In MarkLogic a document would be one invoice. Not the list of invoices. Not one line of the invoice. One entire invoice, with its date, its total and all its lines.

Comment: Can you give us the exact Memory setting which we can increase in AdminUI ?

Comment: Re Florent: you may have reasons to split at line, section, or article level, but a good rule of thumb.

Comment: @SinghVK: you would be looking for the **in-memory-list size** setting on the database you are targeting.

Comment: Thanks. It worked and issue is now resolved.